# how to make a one-digit number a capture group

Tags: regex, perl

I want to connect the below in perl

```
ab0 with NC_ab0
ab1 with NC_ab1
...
```

I want to use something like

```
Connect ab\d ab${1}.
```

However, the `\d` can't form a capture group.
Any idea how I can make it a capture group and use `${1}` to refer to it?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't `\d` form a capture group? Just put parentheses around it like any other group.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what you think *can* form a capture group. This is "Perl Street 'Smarts' 101" -- what do people believe, and why do they believe it.

Comment: Shouldn't you also use `^$` anchors in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put parenthesis around the `\d` if you want to match that value to somewhere else in your regex.

Then use `\1` to refer to the capture group in the LHS of the regex, as `$1` is meant for use in the RHS of a substitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/ab(\d) with NC_ab\1/) {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
ab0 with NC_ab0
ab1 with NC_ab1
ab1 with NC_ab5
ab3 with NC_ab1
```

Outputs:

```
ab0 with NC_ab0
ab1 with NC_ab1
```

This is my current best guess by what your question meant.  If this is incorrect, please reframe the question.